# Mono 3.2.3 + Ubuntu 12: .Net 4.5 Unavailable?

Tags: mono, ubuntu-12.04

I used the following instructions to install Mono on a clean install of Ubuntu 12. 
http://forums.osgrid.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=4625

When I run `mono --runtime=v4.5 Test.exe`, I get the following error:

> WARNING: The runtime version supported by this application is
>   unavailable. Using default runtime: v2.0.50727.

If I set the runtime to v4.0, the program will run initially until it reaches a .Net 4.5 only method, specifically `Monitor.IsEntered`, causing a `MissingMethodException` to be thrown.

I do have a directory called `/opt/mono-3.2.3/lib/mono/4.5.`

How do I fix Mono so I can run this program under the 4.5 framework?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you [found the answer](http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/System-Threading-Monitor-IsEntered-Will-this-be-implemented-td4661494.html): Mono hasn't implement `Monitor.IsEntered()` yet.

It's interesting why this TODO is not evident from the [Mono Class Status](http://go-mono.com/status/) page, though...